# Invalid value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the "Vue Stripe Checkout 3" component, and when I try to implement it, I get the following error "

```
Invalid value for Stripe (): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined.
```

In my data I have:

```
publishableKey: process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
```

Also I tried putting adding my key directly (publishableKey: 'my key') and it still didn't work. I also tried putting it in the prop directly and nothing.

```
<template>
<div>
          <stripe-checkout 
          ref="checkoutRef" 
          :pk="publishableKey"
          :items="items"
          :successUrl="successUrl"
          :cancelUrl="cancelUrl">

    <template slot="checkout-button">
      <button @click="checkout" class="btn-yellow wow fadeInUp btn" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">Pagar</button>
    </template>
  </stripe-checkout>
       
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe-checkout';

export default {
   components: {
    StripeCheckout
  },
   data: () => ({
    loading: false,
publishableKey: 'sk_test_51H85e2F5x69G5dDPxFEtO0RyIBWBEWkqwV9fpN5ovLysfCxJ15kfyeALoUFdZNi57yt0zj40h4LV3l5Zkra6WPCw00by0N0W3a',
    items: [
      {
        sku: item.sku, 
        quantity: 1
      }
    ],
    successUrl: 'https://tarfut.es',
    cancelUrl: 'https://tarfut.es',
  }),
    
    methods: {
      checkout () {
      this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
    },
    },
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same error with Stripe in my next.js app.

Comment: The arrow function could be problematic when declaring Vue functions. Have you tried defining the data method as `data () { ... }` instead?

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar error in my Next.js app, which I've solved by type casting the key to a `string`.

Try replacing:

```js
publishableKey: process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
```

with:

```js
publishableKey: `${process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY}`,
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that your are not specifying to your nuxt application which env variable you want to set.

You have to precise in your `nuxt.config.js` which one needs to be accessible from production.

```
export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    env: {
        API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
        STRIPE_API_KEY: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY,
        GOOGLE_ANALYTICS: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS
        ...
    },
    ...
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/).

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem after two days of WTF!!!